# Create a new cmake input variable

Tags: build, cmake, cmake-gui

is it possible to create a new cmake variable ?
when I run cmake through gui

> ccmake .

a set of variables appear on the screen . I want an extra variable which could have three string values and depending on those strings I can modify my build options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The input variables shown in all CMake UIs are cache variables. You can create your own using `set( ... CACHE)` calls.

To create a "select one of three values" type of variable, you could do this:

```
set(MY_SELECTION "Option A" CACHE STRING "Help message for this variable")
set_property(
  CACHE MY_SELECTION
  PROPERTY STRINGS
  "Option A" "Option B" "Option C"
)
```

This will create a variable named `MY_SELECTION` visible in CMake UI, whose values can be chosen from between `Option A`, `Option B`, and `Option C`. Its initial value will be `Option A` and its help string will be `Help message for this variable`.

Note that `set(... CACHE ...)` calls only affect the variable's value if that variable does not yet exist. If the user already entered their own value, it will *not* be overridden (which is typically what you want in such case).